# Multisite - create a category in specific site

Tags: categories, multisite

I have a multisite I want to create a category but in a specific site. I used this functions below:

```
wp_create_category('mycategory', 0);
```

but this will create a category on the main site. I keep searching if there will be a built in function in wordpress to create a category in a specific site but it seems there is not.

Is there any easy way to create a category in a specific site?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `wp_create_category()` will create a category on the site that you are currently visiting. Of course if you use the same theme for several sites (including your 'main' site), then the category will be added to them as well.  Perhaps you could include more code showing use exactly where and how this code is executed?  But on first view I'd suggest wrapping the code in an `if` statement (`if( get_current_blog_id() == $target_blog_id)...`). Of course that may be utterly wrong, but without more code I don't know - context is king!

Comment: Have you tried `switch_to_blog( $site_id );`?

Comment: @toscho nop! I will try it :)

Comment: @toscho thanks :) fixed my problem by doing this switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
// Do something
restore_current_blog();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and maybe [get_blog_id_from_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_id_from_url) which you would use like this:

```
$blog_id = get_blog_id_from_url( 'www.example.com' );
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
wp_create_category( 'mycategory', 0 );
restore_current_blog();
```